# Post was put on hold stating that code is not working

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed

I have a question about my Code Review Stack Exchange post: [Filling-values-for-dictionary-of-dictionaries](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/203655/filling-values-for-dictionary-of-dictionaries)

Post was put on hold stating that code is not working but it's working and I had posted the results.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not mistaken your code didn't work at the time it was closed.

You fixed it, it works now.

Your post is already in the reopen queue, people are able to vote on it so I believe it should be reopened if the code works (which seems to be the case but I flew over it quickly)

Comment: No it was working when it was closed after that i got comment from @mast to indent the code which was pep8,flake8 issue and  not affecting the functionality of the code which i had fixed.

Comment: @user3777713 Don't worry about this too much. When you edited your code it was probably already in the close queue so it was closed. I think it's bad luck with the timing. As I said now that it's in the reopen queue it should be reopened if there are no other mistakes. Mistakes can happen :)

Comment: I pushed through the reopen.... I agree that it was probably just bad timing of when the edit came through, and the "inertia" of the close review queue.